# How to include regex pattern matches into substitution output

Tags: regex

For example, if I want to add a space in-between all instances where I have one uppercase letter preceding a hyphen (A-, C-, etc...), then what function can I use to achieve this?

Alternatively, is there a way to get re.sub to output the pattern that was matched? :

```
>>> text = 'T- AB-'
>>> re.sub(r'\b[A-Z]-', 'what goes here?', text)
>>> text
'T - AB-'
```

Comment: Groups/backreferences - [`re.sub(r'\b([A-Z])-', r'\1 -', text)`](https://ideone.com/1NKj1m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to use capturing parenthesis and a \1

```
import re

text = 'T- AB-'
text = re.sub(r'\b([A-Z])-', r'\1 -', text)
print (text)
```

results:

```
T - AB-
```

That should do the trick.  Whatever you capture in the ( ) can be referenced with \1.  If you had a series of parenthesis each set can be referenced like \2, \3, etc.  Good luck!